# How to prove the determinate of the cartan matrix of a group ring is positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, determinant

I'm reading the text *Representations of Finite Groups* by Nagao and Tsushima. In an exercise, it asked to prove $\det C > 0,$ where $C$ is the Cartan matrix of a group ring $RG$ and $R$ is a complete discrete valuation ring.

I know that $C = D' D$ (where $D$ is the decomposition matrix of $RG$ and $D'$ is the transpose of $D$) and $D$ has full column rank. If $D$ is a square matrix, then it's obvious that $\det C = (\det D)^2 > 0,$ but the problem is that $D$ is usually not a square matrix.

If you don't have a background of group representation theory, my question is

> if $C=D'D$ $(C$ and $D$ are integer matrices) and $D$ has full column rank, does $\det C > 0$ hold?

Comment: If $D$ has full column rank, and real entries, then $C$ is positive definite.

Comment: The entries of $D$ is positive, of course, but that does not meant that ${\rm det}C$ is positive.

Comment: The signs of the entries of $D$ are irrelevant: $C$ is positive definite, and positive definite matrices have positive determinant.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've almost forgotten the properties of positive definite matrices, and without using this property, it seems not obvious to drew this conclusion.